# Dataframe transformation and string concatenate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
index, a, b
0, i, this
1, belong, is 
2, here, right
0, only, one
0, two, another
1, items, example
```

And I am trying to get the output so that running indexes get folded up and concatenates the strings:

```
index, a, b
0, i belong here, this is right
1, only, one
2, two items, another example
```

Any idea how to do this in a clean way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need create groups starting with `0` in `index` and cumulative sum, then aggregate `join`:

```
#if index is column
df = df.groupby(df['index'].eq(0).cumsum(), as_index=False).agg(' '.join)
#if index is not column
#df = df.groupby((df.index == 0).cumsum(), as_index=False).agg(' '.join)
print (df)
               a                b
0  i belong here   this is  right
1           only              one
2      two items  another example
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['index'].eq(0).cumsum())
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    3
Name: index, dtype: int32

#print ((df.index == 0).cumsum())
#[1 1 1 2 3 3]
```

Comment: `df['index'].eq(0)` gives True in each row where index = 0, doing a cumsum gives you groups of 1,2 and 3 since the other values are false, then groupby them and join the strings. +1@jezrael that was superfast